# How can I make a class agnostic of its members type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class

```
template <typename T> 
class Templated {
    T someValue;
    //... 
};
```

and another class with a member of type `Templated`.

```
class Holder {
    Templated t;
    //...
};
```

This would not compile, because actual type of `Holder::Templated` is not known. I want `Holder::Templated` to be initialized / created later, it's value and also type will be read from a configuration file. How can I create `Holder` objects but add the actual `Holder::Templated` members later?

I could have a base class to `Templated` and hold the base class pointer in the `Holder` class, but I don't like this option. Do you have any other ideas to keep the `Holder` class agnostic of the type of its `Templated` member?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll need some kind of type erasure then. If C++17 is an option, you might want to try [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

Comment: You're out of luck. Templates are a compile-time feature. Polymorphism might be a better tool for your job.

Comment: Thanks @lubgr, C++14 unfortunately. However you gave me a keyword to read about.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to keep a pointer to `templated`s base class inside holder, you can add a layer of indirection and have `templated` itself hold a pointer to its concrete implementation.

```
class Holder {
    Untemplated u;
    //...
};

class Untemplated {
    //...
     struct Templated_base {
        //... virtual interface
     };
     Templated_base* hook; // or better with smart pointers

     template <typename T>
     struct Templated : Templated_base {
        // ... final interface
     };

     template <typename T>
     Untemplated(T&& x) { hook = new  Templated<T>(std::forward<T>(x)); }
};
```

This is only a rough sketch of an elaborate strategy devised by Sean Parent (see this: http://sean-parent.stlab.cc/papers-and-presentations/#better-code-runtime-polymorphism), which allows to use dynamic polymorphism somewhere without paying a price everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @papagaga, this one looks actually promising.

Comment: Ah, was it really Sean Parent who *devised* it? He certainly presents it spectacularly, but devising the technique is quite an attribution.

Comment: @StoryTeller: you tell me the story then!

Comment: @papagaga - You made the claim, so *you* back it up. That's where burden of proof is, not on me to disprove it.

Comment: @StoryTeller: here's my proof: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.89.1257

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) to hold a value of any type or [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to hold values from a set of types. E.g.:

```
#include <any>

class Holder {
    std::any t;
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are purely a compile-time polymorphism construct. You need run-time polymorphism, which can be achieved in many different ways in C++:

- Inheritance + `virtual` functions: useful when you have an interface and an open set of implementors;
- [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant): useful when you have a known closed set of choices;
- [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any): useful when you want to store any arbitrary object without any restriction
- More: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno), ...